# Any know of good examples and documentation on bzr

Tags: bazaar

Any know of good examples and documentation on bzr (bazaar) and the common tasks like merging (IE. books, FAQs, wiki, etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with [the official Bazaar documentation](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/en/)?

Comment: I don't know, I just like having examples / documentation from people that use it

Comment: Oh wow, Actually I haven't seen that documentation page before, even though I have read the official documentation.